# ListView's onEndReached, in react native, is not working as expected

Tags: android, listview, react-native

This is my code for a component's render.

```
render() {
  let loadMore;
  let hasMore = this.props.end && this.props.photos.length < this.props.end;

  if (hasMore) {
    loadMore = (
      <View style={globalStyles.ContChild}>
        <Button
          onPress={() => this.loadMoreItems()}
          containerStyle={globalStyles.bottomButton}
          style={globalStyles.buttonText}
          >
          Load more
        </Button>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.photos)}
        renderRow={this._renderPhoto}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
          marginLeft: 4,
        }}
        enableEmptySections={true}
        initialListSize={12}
        pageSize={12 * 3}
        onEndReached={hasMore ? (() => this.loadMoreItems()) : null}
        onEndReachedThreshold="32"
      />
      {loadMore}
    </View>
  );
}
```

It is intended that the ListView, when scrolled to the bottom but 32px or less, perform an additional data load.

Right now the data load works via a button labeled "Load More", as it is generated in the if-condition in the render method. The button is conditionally added inside the View component, right below the ListView.

Currently, when you click the button, the `loadMore()` logic is executed and loads more pictures accordingly. The loaded data is a list of pictures (the listview is a photo gallery).

I wanted to remove the button and use the *when the listview is scrolled to the bottom* logic, by using the `onEndReached` handler. Right now both logics coexist in my system, but there is a problem -or misunderstanding since I started yesterday on this project- with the onEndReached logic, even if using the threshold:

Right now the onEndReached logic is executed eagerly, on each render cycle (IIRC a new render cycle is triggered when the data changes, and the data changes on each `loadMore`call), as if each render cycle considered that `onEndReached` should trigger. However: the listview is not scrolled to the end in any case. It is still in the very scrolling top.

My purpose: I don't want the whole pictures be loaded eagerly, but in a scroll-paginated fashion, i.e. when the scrolling bottom is reached, load more elements automatically (with no need to either press the Load More button -since I will remove that button- and no eager loading but scrolling).

My question: What am I doing wrong regarding this event and how could I fix it?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
<ListView 
    ref={(listView) => { _listView = listView; }}
    dataSource={this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.photos)}
    renderRow={this._renderPhoto}
    contentContainerStyle={{
      flexDirection: 'row',
      flexWrap: 'wrap',
      marginLeft: 4,
    }}
    enableEmptySections={true}
    initialListSize={12}
    pageSize={12 * 3}
    onEndReached={hasMore ? (() => this.loadMoreItems()) : null}
    onEndReachedThreshold="32"
  />
```

I missed to use ref in my ListView, and was facing the same problem. Once I added those, my pagination is working correctly.